# Can you replace android database?

Tags: android

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to do a backup of my database from my app. I can pull the database.db from the data/data/databases, but when I cleared the data and try to import the copy of the db to data/data/databases nothing happen.

The question is can you not modify data/data/databases?

Comment: you want to restore the backup in the app

Comment: yes I want to copy the backup back to data/data/databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the Code for Backup And Restore the Database

```
 private void importDB() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "<package name>"
                        + "//databases//" + "<database name>";
                String backupDBPath = "<backup db filename>"; 
                File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}

private void exportDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "<package name>"
                    + "//databases//" + "<db name>";
            String backupDBPath = "<destination>";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked but I have to replace the currentDBPath  to backupDBPath and vice versa in the importDB().